# Why is my simple calculation in jQuery text not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to update a number with jQuery. The number is a string so I do

```
mon = parseInt($('.money').text())
```

I also need to take another number and I do that the same way.

Then I need to add something to it and for that I use the following script:

```
mon = parseInt($('.money').text());
mat = parseInt($('.materials').text());
$('.money').text(  mon + parseInt($('.'+ next_row).find('.'+next_cell).data('income')) );
$('.materials').text(  mat + parseInt($('.'+ next_row).find('.'+next_cell).data('mat')) );
```

As you can see, I also grab something from it with the data attribute. I change that to a integer. So I now count 2 integers so that should work. Then I change the number on the screen with the text() attribute, but the output is NaN.

What I am doing wrong?

**Edit:**
HTML:

```
<div class="stats">
    <ul>
        <li><b>Money: </b><p class="money">10000</p></li>
        <li><b>Materials: </b><p class="materials">1000</p></li>
        <li><b>inhabitants: </b><p class="people">2</p></li>
        <li><b>Buildings: </b><p class="buildings">0</p></li>
        <li><b>Time: </b><p class="time">0</p></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: One or more of the values you're using clearly isn't a number, so you end up with `NaN`. There's only one thing to do, log each value and see which one is the issue.

Comment: I don't see how this question would be appropriate for code review given that the OP is asking a question about an error he is having - unless I'm missing something.

Comment: @Qwerty No, so can you tell what it is?

Comment: @Vinc199789 show us the HTML and the value of your variables, my guess is that you selector doesn't return the good element so the parseInt of you data return undefined.

Comment: @Qwerty this question is not a good canidate for code review....

Comment: `console.log()` the parts you are adding together. Find out what part is causing the problem.

Comment: Do the values pulled from the DOM have prefixed currency symbols? If so, they will need to be stripped off before `parseInt()` can do its thing on the number part.

Comment: @epascarello I did console.log on everything but they all told NaN

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon I added the html

Comment: And where are the data attributes in the html?

Comment: @epascarello I found the problem. With Jquery I add images and they contains the data attributes, but what I did was that I searched for the cell and not for the images in that cell. Thanks for your comment. Can you also tell me Why somebody downvoted my question?

Comment: because someone thought this question will not be useful to others.

Comment: where are your `next_row` and `next_cell` variables?

Comment: There is something wrong with these lines: parseInt($('.'+ next_row).find('.'+next_cell).data('income'))
parseInt($('.'+ next_row).find('.'+next_cell).data('mat')) Because when I changed them to the number 5 both of them everything worked just fine.